# Issue to execute mysql stored procedure file in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a stored procedure in `mySQL` when running script in phpmyadmin it give syntax error. When create manually it execute.Anyhelp would be appreciated

[image]

It shows error when i run through `SQL` Query when I do manually phpmyadmin stored procedure function it create it

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_ConsolidatedFollowFeedUserList`(
 _uid INT,
 _startTime INT,
 _endTime INT,
 _activityType VARCHAR(150),
 `_follow_to` INT,
 `_offset` INT,
 `_limit` INT
)
BEGIN

 SELECT
  feed.id `feed_id`,
  activity.id ` activity_id`,
  activity.uid AS `uid`,
  activity.source_id AS follow_to,
  activity.activity_type,
  activity.source_id,
  activity.parent_id,
  activity.parent_type,
  activity.post_id
 FROM
  `user_feed` feed
 JOIN user_activity activity ON feed.activity_id = activity.id
 WHERE
  feed.uid = _uid
  AND feed.`status` = 'ACTIVE'
  AND activity.`status` = 'ACTIVE'
  AND activity.activity_type IN(_activityType)
  AND activity.created BETWEEN startTime AND endTime
  AND activity.source_id = _follow_to
 ORDER BY
  activity.created DESC
 LIMIT 
  offset, limit;

END
```

Comment: What help do you exactly expect if you do not share any details with us?

Comment: And are you sure that your live server allows the execution of stored procedure ?

Comment: @Shadow a simple stored procedure sql file works fine in local but not in hosting environment

Comment: @SuperPeanut how to identify that live server phpmyadmin allow stored procedure sql query

Comment: I don't know... Is it a hosted service from a third company ? If yes, ask them. Is it a server running on your building ? If yes, check the manual regarding your server version. SO does not do magic, I don't know your infrastructure...

Comment: @SuperPeanut it allows to make Stored procedure by their manual feature but not allowing through script

Comment: Well there is your answer...

Comment: @SuperPeanut You're being rude whether you meant it or not. The question is not well asked and hard to help but the way you're communicating is not well accepted on SO. You may guide OP to write a better question.

Comment: @Shaharyar I'm sorry I don't mean to be rude at all. With the updated image it is actually easier to tell... Could you actually copy/paste the procedure you were executing in PHPMyAdmin ? As it is not a privilege error but a syntax one...

Answer (score 0):

If your stored procedure is in a file, then you don't need the `` to protect the column fields. Then your parameter names have to match exactly `offset` is not matching `_offset`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_ConsolidatedFollowFeedUserList`(
     _uid INT,
     _startTime INT,
     _endTime INT,
     _activityType VARCHAR(150),
     _follow_to INT,
     _offset INT,
     _limit INT)

BEGIN

 SELECT
  feed.id AS feed_id,
  activity.id AS activity_id,
  activity.uid AS uid,
  activity.source_id AS follow_to,
  activity.activity_type,
  activity.source_id,
  activity.parent_id,
  activity.parent_type,
  activity.post_id

 FROM
  user_feed AS feed
  JOIN user_activity activity ON feed.activity_id = activity.id
 WHERE
  feed.uid = _uid
  AND feed.status = 'ACTIVE'
  AND activity.status = 'ACTIVE'
  AND activity.activity_type IN (_activityType)
  AND activity.created BETWEEN _startTime AND _endTime
  AND activity.source_id = _follow_to
 ORDER BY activity.created DESC
 LIMIT _offset, _limit;

END
```